# Refactor AngularJS to use controllerAs, apply CSS for a required input once it is not empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

What would be the most efficient way of conditionally changing the background color for a required input once it is valid using AngularJS 1.5.6? Per my understanding and what I have [read online](https://daveceddia.com/convert-scope-to-controlleras/), I should avoid using $scope and instead use controllerAs. How would I refactor to the follow AngularJS code to use controllerAs?

## Only CSS and HTML

HTML

```
<input id='textfield' placeholder='Search'  required>
```

CSS

```
#textfield:valid {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

## Using $scope

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="text" ng-class="cssClass" ng-change="changeCssInput()" ng-model="text"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-green {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.input-red {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('testController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.text = '';
    $scope.cssClass = 'input-red';    
    $scope.changeCssInput = function () {
        $scope.cssClass = $scope.text.length <= 0 ? 'input-red' : 'input-green';  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way of conditionally changing the
>   background color for a required input once it is valid using AngularJS
>   1.5.6?

*(Below code is written using `controllerAs` syntax, see below for more info about `controllerAs` syntax)*

```
<input type="text" ng-class="ctrl.text.length <= 0 ? 'input-red' : 'input-green'" ng-model="ctrl.text"/>
```

> How would I refactor to the follow AngularJS code to use controllerAs?

Using **controllerAs** syntax

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-class="ctrl.cssClass" ng-change="ctrl.changeCssInput()" ng-model="ctrl.text"/>
</div>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('testController', function ()
{
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.wizard = {
        text : '',
        cssClass : 'input-red',
        changeCssInput : changeCssInput,
    };   

    return ctrl.wizard;

    function changeCssInput() {
        ctrl.wizard.cssClass = ctrl.wizard.text.length <= 0 ? 'input-red' : 'input-green';  
    }
});
```